# Use NodeJS server response with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a NodeJS server, that receive HTML req, and I need him to resend the req to the client, 
So I want to use res.writehead()....
But I don't know how to use the sent data in Javascript.
Thank you very much
Nathan

Comment: what you have tried so far? Share some code

Comment: Nothing because I have absolute no idea of how to filter and use the NodeJS response in Javascript

Comment: @NathanLoisel you have any experience writing web application using any other tech stack?

Comment: Sorry that I ask but that's required to understand what kind of confusion you might have

Comment: Not really @binariedMe

Comment: Can you start a chat thread to make it easy for us and others?

Comment: No enough reputation to talk